# PHP Concatenating arrays (lists) and ignoring duplicate keys, because we just use values

Tags: php, arrays

We have a list (array) in php that is setup like

```
$update_product_ids = array();
array_push($update_product_ids, (int)$product->getId()); // (int)$product->getId() is an integer

The I tried:
array_push($update_product_ids, array_values($child_ids)); // child_ids is an array of integers
and
array_merge($update_product_ids, $child_ids); // child_ids is an array of integers
```

This did not work and it looks like the keys are being merged in either example instead of being added to the end. I think this is because php does not store arrays as `('A', 'B')` but rather as `(0=>'A',1=>'B')` and the 2 arrays I am merging both have keys `0 and 1`.

So I resolved to

```
foreach ($children_ids as $child_id) {
    array_push($update_product_ids, (int)$child_id);
}
```

Which feels a little silly because there must be a way to do this correct in 1 go?

question: how can I merge the above arrays in 1 go?

Comment: Did you tried `array_unique(array_merge($update_product_ids,$child_ids))`?

Comment: `array_merge` works fine. And `('A', 'B')` is the same as `(0=>'A',1=>'B')`. https://3v4l.org/cMLJ6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with `array_merge`. Unlike `array_push`, `array_merge` does not modify the arrays provided. It rather returns a new array that is the concatenation of the arrays provided. So basically, do something like:

```
$update_product_ids = array_merge($update_product_ids, $child_ids);
```

---

If you are using PHP 5.6 (or greater), you can also use the "argument unpacking":

```
array_push($update_product_ids, ...$child_ids);
```

---

If you are using PHP 7.4 (or greater), you can use the "spread operator" (same as argument unpacking, but for arrays):

```
$update_product_ids = [...$update_product_ids, ...$child_ids];
```

Comment: What result did you get?

Comment: Would any of the above do the exact same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/63314722/1173670

Comment: No, it won't. You are comparing two arrays while in the answer above we are "concatenating" two arrays.

Comment: Hi. Sorry, No. Your question is asking about how to merge arrays in the specific situation you explained. That's what the answer above is trying to do. Have you tried the answer? Did it work?